# Change color of the area below the last section of a uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sectionheader

I have a UITableView. I figured out how to change the background color for the section headers. However, it also changes the bottom area that contains "no section/rows" to the same color. I don't want this.

Is there anyway I can set the color of that area to be a different color than the section headers?

See example picture for more information.[image: Area in blue at the bottom is the part that I want to be a different color]

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've done research but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Hm... That's strange. Could you post your code from `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` and your header methods?

Comment: I actually did this one in Interface Builder. The only thing that I did via code for this `willDisplayHeaderView' method and it was used only to set the text color of the section headers.

Comment: did you set background color for table view?

Comment: In IB to set the section color background, I changed the background color for the View. It seems like that is what affects all 3 areas. Is there a way to set only the section header colors programmatically?

Comment: may be you can return a custom view with blue color using tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method

Comment: @Clement in `viewForHeaderInSection` method, I did this:

`UIView *view = self.tableView.tableFooterView;
    
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return view;`

Now I'm getting this error: Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead. 

My application also crashes after doing this. So, I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: @Clement I figured out how to add just a color to the section headers. In `willDisplayHeaderView` method, I was able to get the contentView and was able to set the background color by doing this: 
`UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` However, for some reason the second header has a white line above it -- like there is some kind of padding added.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I had to do was:

In Interface Builder, change the color of the view to what you want displayed at the bottom.

I used the same color that I had set for my table cell rows.

For the section headers:

In the `willDisplayHeaderView` method, do:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Please note: If you get a white/gray line above the section header - this deals with the footer. So, in `viewDidLoad` method, set the table footer height to 0:

```
self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0;
```